Where do we say racism/ethnic criticism is not OK - even outside user-to-user interaction - in the site's help content?
Suggested a new user take a look at our posting guidelines when they wrote up a question with, among things, repeated criticism about a particular ethnic group:

Greater Ewoks are cheats and eschew showers

Well, it should be obvious racism and similar stuff won't be tolerated in questions or answers, but where is it actually stated in the guidelines/help?
I quoted the code of conduct

We do not allow advocating for violence or encouraging harm to others. We do not allow discriminatory content towards a person’s actual or perceived ethnicity, age, sexual orientation, gender identity and expression, and/or disabilities. We also do not allow content that supports, celebrates, or furthers the cause of extremist organizations as per our Abusive Behavior policy.

OK, that's fine, as far as person to person interactions go, I guess.  But the OP wasn't calling me anything, as I am a Lesser Ewok, so have no reason to feel offended.
So what says "don't post bigoted contents, regardless of whom it is addressed to, it'll be taken down?"
In the past someone cited the code of conduct, which seemed to have different contents:

We don’t tolerate any language likely to offend or alienate people based on race, gender, sexual orientation, or religion — and those are just a few examples. When in doubt, just don’t.

Notice, this is not about calling me names (which I don't doubt the current CoC covers).
It's just saying don't call groups as a whole bad things and it applies directly to this question.
So where is something similar found nowadays, so that I can just point a user to it without engaging in a debate about it?

I don't quite follow your assertion that the policy only applies to person to person interactions. A Greater Ewok that doesn't use this site would still be a "person", so your example would still be discriminatory against that person.

The document you linked also refers to the Abusive Behavior Policy, which, among other things, says:

we do not allow behaviors or content that cause or contribute to an atmosphere that excludes, marginalizes, or dehumanizes individuals or communities on the basis of their actual or perceived ethnicity, age, sexual orientation, gender identity and expression, disability, or held religious beliefs.
[...]
Bigotry & Discrimination – the poor treatment, expressed irrational suspicion, hatred, targeting, and/or intolerance of another person or group of people due to their ethnicity, age, sexual orientation, gender identity and expression, disability, or held religious beliefs.

Ewoks are an example of such a community / group of people.
But please remember that when you witness such behavior, then it is everyone's duty to flag the content. You don't need to waste your time and mental health on debating bigots. That's the job of us moderators.

This assumes that "cheats and eschew showers" is a criticism rather than a compliment.  For the community of water-averse witches (for example) saying that someone eschews showers would almost certainly be a compliment.
